# add data to xml file at every mouse click

Tags: c#, .net, xml, mouseevent, linq-to-xml

i have to add data to an xml file everytime the mouse event happens! here is my code i will explain you better after you having a glance at it.

```
 private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {


            if (radioButton1.Checked==true)
            {
                if (a > 3 && a < 11)
                {

                    rect.Width = 0;
                    rect.Height = 0;
                    pictureBox1.Invalidate();


                 raghu =   img.imageToByteArray(pictureBox1.Image);


                    int radius = 10; //Set the number of pixel you want to use here
                    //Calculate the numbers based on radius
                    int x0 = Math.Max(e.X - (radius / 2), 0),
                        y0 = Math.Max(e.Y - (radius / 2), 0),
                        x1 = Math.Min(e.X + (radius / 2), pictureBox1.Width),
                        y1 = Math.Min(e.Y + (radius / 2), pictureBox1.Height);
                    Bitmap bm = pictureBox1.Image as Bitmap; //Get the bitmap (assuming it is stored that way)
                    for (int ix = x0; ix < x1; ix++)
                    {
                        for (int iy = y0; iy < y1; iy++)
                        {
                            bm.SetPixel(ix, iy, Color.Black); //Change the pixel color, maybe should be relative to bitmap
                        }
                    }
                    pictureBox1.Refresh(); //Force refresh

                    //calculation part.
                    float u = l[p + 1] - l[p];
                    float v = m[p + 1] - m[p];
                    float w = (e.Y - m[p]) / v;//subtract from latitude
                    float z = (e.X - l[p]) / u;//add to longitude.
                    float latmin = h[p] - w;
                    float longmin = j[p] + z;

                    A1 = e.X - c[p];
                    A2 = e.Y - d[p];
                    B1 = c[p + 1] - c[p];
                    B2 = d[p + 1] - d[p];
                    A = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(A1, 2) + Math.Pow(A2, 2));
                    B = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(B1, 2) + Math.Pow(B2, 2));
                    dotproduct = A1 * B1 + A2 * B2;
                    theta = (180 / Math.PI) * Math.Acos(dotproduct / (A * B));
                    if (e.X < c[p])
                    {
                        theta1 = 360 - theta;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        theta1 = theta;
                    }
                    textBox2.Text = string.Format("Latitude:{0}°{1}'{2}''\n Longitude:{3}°{4}'{5}'' \n ICAO LOC: {6} {7} \n Distance: {8:0.0} Nm", g[p] + (int)latmin / 60, (int)latmin % 60,(int) (((h[p]-w) % 60 - (int)(latmin % 60)) * 60), i[p] + (int)longmin / 60, (int)longmin % 60, (int)((longmin % 60 - (int)(longmin % 60)) * 60), textBox1.Text, Math.Abs((int)theta1), Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((A1/u)* 60, 2) + Math.Pow((A2/v) * 60, 2)));
```

There is a lot of calculation part which is not necessary now.But the data i am going to print in the textBox2(last line of code) is important.all that data that is printed there should be added to an Xml file each time i click the mouse on the picturebox...

so I tried to implement by using xdocument by adding this way..

```
             XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(string.Format("{0}.xml", textBox3.Text));
                    XElement ParentNode= xdoc.Root.Element(string.Format("{0}",radioButton1.Text));
                    XElement node= new XElement("WayPoints",new XElement("LatitudeDegrees",g[p] + (int)latmin / 60 ,
                                     new XAttribute("Minutes",(int)latmin % 60),
                                         new XAttribute("Seconds",(int)(((h[p] - w) % 60 - (int)(latmin % 60)) * 60)),
                                            new XElement("LongitudeDegrees",i[p] + (int)longmin / 60,
                                                new XAttribute("Minutes",(int)longmin % 60),
                                                  new XAttribute("seconds",(int)((longmin % 60 - (int)(longmin % 60)) * 60)),
                                                     new XElement ("IcaoLocator",textBox1.Text,
                                                         new XAttribute("angle",Math.Abs((int)theta1)),
                                                         new XElement("DistanceInNauticalMiles",Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((A1 / u) * 60, 2) + Math.Pow((A2 / v) * 60, 2))

                )))));
                    ParentNode.Add(node);
                    xdoc.Save(string.Format("{0}.xml", textBox3.Text));
```

But the problem is it is saying that the root element is Missing.

Actually the file I am  loading in the Xdocument is ,I already created it

```
  using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(string.Format("{0}.xml", textBox3.Text)))
            { 
            }
```

previously here like this(because I fear that if create it is created in Picturebox_Mouseclick it gets over written)

```
 private void pictureBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

            if (a > 1 && a <= 3)
            {
                c[f] = e.X;
                d[f] = e.Y;
                a++;
                f++;
            }
          using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(string.Format("{0}.xml", textBox3.Text)))
            { 
            }
    }
```

Dont bother if you dont understand the calculation ,its specific to my needs I only need to print the data to xml file..please any one kindly help me..

one example of way point is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WayPoints>
  <Latitude>
    <Degrees>48</Degrees>
    <Minutes>31.7363644</Minutes>
  </Latitude>
  <Longitude>
    <Degrees>11</Degrees>
    <Minutes>57.53425</Minutes>
  </Longitude>
  <IcaoLocator>
    <Type>EDML</Type>
    <Angle>288</Angle>
    <DistanceInPixels>346</DistanceInPixels>
  </IcaoLocator>
</WayPoints>
```

but it contains only one way point ..I ned to add a lot of waypoints to this XML file.

Comment: Can you show us what the xml-file looks like (not how you want it to look at first, but what's actually in it). Cause the exception sounds like you have several root-elements, which is illegal in xml (at least to my knowledge)

Comment: just as side comment, you are doing in the UI all the business logic and data manipulation which is generally a bad design. Can't you create some helper classes and move calculations and XML manipulation to those classes and keep the UI simpler?

Comment: @Alxandr...I have added an example to the question ,please check it!!

Comment: @David.. what you said is correct but Iam completely new to it!! should learn it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that there is in fact (as the exception states) no root element for the xml. This can be fixed fairly simple by changing the layout of the xml to something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WayPoints>
   <WayPoint>
      <Latitude>
        <Degrees>48</Degrees>
        <Minutes>31.7363644</Minutes>
      </Latitude>
      <Longitude>
        <Degrees>11</Degrees>
        <Minutes>57.53425</Minutes>
      </Longitude>
      <IcaoLocator>
        <Type>EDML</Type>
        <Angle>288</Angle>
        <DistanceInPixels>346</DistanceInPixels>
      </IcaoLocator>
   </WayPoint>
   <WayPoint> <!-- New waypoint here, not at the root -->
      <Latitude>
        <Degrees>48</Degrees>
        <Minutes>31.7363644</Minutes>
      </Latitude>
      <Longitude>
        <Degrees>11</Degrees>
        <Minutes>57.53425</Minutes>
      </Longitude>
      <IcaoLocator>
        <Type>EDML</Type>
        <Angle>288</Angle>
        <DistanceInPixels>346</DistanceInPixels>
      </IcaoLocator>
   </WayPoint>
</WayPoints>
```

Then you should be able to do this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("PATH_TO_FILE.xml");
doc.Element("WayPoints").Add(new XElement("WayPoint", 
    new XElement("Latitude",
        new XElement("Degrees", 48),
        new XElement("Minutes", 31.7363644),
    ),
    new XElement("Longitude",
        new XElement("Degrees", 48),
        new XElement("Minutes", 31.7363644),
    ),
    new XElement("IcaoLocator",
        new XElement("Type", "EDML"),
        new XElement("Angle", 288),
        new XElement("DistanceInPixels", 346)
    )
);
doc.Save("PATH_TO_FILE.xml");
```

Not tested (don't have visual studio on this computer).

Answer (score 1):

When you use the xml writer to create the xml file, you dont put any elements in it, so when XDocument goes to load it, it doesnt find a root element and throws the exception you're getting.

i suggest skipping the xmlwriter and initializing the XDocument to a new XDocument if the file doesnt exist:

```
XDocument xdoc;
if( File.Exist( string.Format("{0}.xml", textBox3.Text ) ) )
  xdoc = XDocument.Load( string.Format( "{0}.xml", textBox3.Text ) );
else
  xdoc = new XDocument(...);
```

Comment: How to create the xml file first? i didnt get you...if it it already exists then we can implement what you said...but how to create the xml file using xdocument

Comment: you can just construct a new XDocument object ([using one of its constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.xdocument.aspx)) and then call the save method as you normally do :) see link for samples